# Transparent background on react-navigation not applying correctly

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, styling

I am currently trying to make a linear gradient background on my app and it works as intended but on the right header there's some container that I can't access. Any ideas? I tried changing the headerRightContainerStyle but that only affects the button on the right and not that empty space. It's weird how only the right side is affected too because the header's left side is the effect I desire

Image: https://ibb.co/cYKj1XV

Code:

```
...
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      title: "Users Page",
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: "transparent",
      },
      headerRightContainerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: "red",
      },
      headerRight: () => <Button title="Next" color={colors.blue} />,
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <LinearGradient
      colors={gradientColorsBackground}
      style={styles.gradientBackground}
    >
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <KeyboardAvoidingView
          style={styles.keyboardAvoidingContainer}
          behavior="padding"
        >
          <KeyboardAwareFlatList
            style={styles.usersList}
            data={users}
            keyExtractor={(item) => `${item.id}`}
            renderItem={({ item }) => <Person name={item.name} id={item.id} />}
          />
          <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            autoFocus={false}
            blurOnSubmit={false}
            placeholder="Type people's names"
            onSubmitEditing={({ nativeEvent: { text } }) => addUser(text)}
            autoCorrect={false}
          />
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </LinearGradient>
  );
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    width: "100%",
  },
  gradientBackground: {
    flex: 1,
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  input: {
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: "orange",
    width: "100%",
    borderStyle: "solid",
    borderWidth: 3,
  },
  keyboardAvoidingContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  usersList: {
    flex: 1,
    width: "100%",
    backgroundColor: colors.blue,
  },
});
...
```

Comment: what version of react nav are you using? I think if you pass a view with flex:1 and the button nested within it, then you can access that area. optionally you can also just pass a whole header component

Comment: I'm using version 4.3.9 and I tried what you suggested with the View option with flex: 1 but it still gives me the same effects as I did with the headerRightContainerStyle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you just need to set `headerTransparent: true`.

```
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      title: "Users Page",
      headerTransparent: true,
      headerRight: () => <Button title="Next" color={colors.blue} />,
    });
  }, []);
```

Docs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/stack-navigator/#headertransparent

Example here: https://snack.expo.io/M230FOH!Q

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to make header color transparent

```
 headerStyle:{ position: 'absolute', backgroundColor: 'transparent', zIndex: 100, top: 0, left: 0, right: 0 }
```

check snack here https://snack.expo.io/lMGBTKXJK

Comment: How does adding position, zIndex, and the top, left, right styling make the header transparent? React Native also tells me that these stylings have no effect on headerstyle.